# Dropzonejs issue with resolution of an image

Tags: drag-and-drop, dpi, dropzone.js

I have an issue with [dropezonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/).
Apparently, when an image has a resolution more than 72dpi, the thumbnail is not generated and everything stop here.

You can try by yourself in the dropzonejs website by uploading different kinds of images. (images <72dpi won't be displayed as thumbnails)

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Very strange. I will try it out, and give feedback. What browser are you using?

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce your problem. Maybe your image files are defect? Please provide more information about your system, and if possible, the files that do not work.

Comment: @enyo This happens when the file uploaded is not in RGB color mode but CMYK instead

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're backend doesn't accept CMYK files. I've had the same issue with JAVA ImageIO, we are making an change in the backend to support the upload of a CMYK file